# Unable to use PolynomialFeatures on tensorflow variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am working with tensorflow. I have a training dataset X_train and I want to create polynomial features from it. Specifically, I want to use *[PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)* from *sklearn.preprocessing*. I'm getting an error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The code that I try to compile is

```
n_features = 3
n_samples = 1000
X_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(n_samples,n_features))
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 3)
poly.fit_transform(X_train)
```